# iPhone Crash log - Is the method name always correct?

Tags: iphone, crash, crash-reports

This is the part of the crash log I am interested in:

```
1   TEST_iPhone_App  0x00043ff2 -[TSClassName methodName] (TSClassName.m:86)
```

Lest say the method looks like this:

```
- (void) methodName {
    // Some code...
    [self otherMethod];   // This is line #86
    // Some more code...
}

- (void) otherMethod {
    // Dubious code... could the crash be here?
}
```

My question is, could it be possible that the crash log refers to `otherMethod`?  Perhaps `otherMethod` is put inline and it cant tell the difference between the two methods, or dose it definitely refer to the code in `methodName`

EDIT: I have had a look at line 86 and it is the call to `otherMethod`.  Does this mean that the instance got released by anouther thread, therefore messaging `self` caused the error?  Or could the error stil be in `otherMethod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have certainly experienced having the top line of the stack trace in the debugger display the calling method of the method where the error actually occurred. If that's the case, though, in your example line `86` of `methodName` would be the closing bracket.

Comment: Just to clarify, the error is in the method that called `methodName` providing that line 86 of the .m file is a `}`?

Comment: @Robert I mean to say that it's line 86 of `methodName` and not line 86 of `otherMethod`, in your example. :)